# Font Icons MUI v5 not showing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use the Icon class from Material UI v5, I added the following to my index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
```

and then I use

```
import { Icon} from '@mui/material';
 <Icon color="inherit">file_download</Icon>
```

But My icons still dont show

Comment: https://mui.com/material-ui/icons/#svg-material-icons

Comment: Have you installed `@mui/material` `@emotion/styled` and `@emotion/react` as your dependencies? I tried your code and it does work and correctly shows the icon: https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-platform-bqe0sb?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Nima Yup They all seem to be installed

Comment: I really don't know what the problem is then. Where are you including `<Icon />`? Check its parent element and see if it is because of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to it working by adding all the Icons in my index.html file

From

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp">
```

I Think some icons dont work if you dont specify all of them in the stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the import path to `import Icon from '@mui/material/Icon';`